# Objective c - ios : How to pick video from Camera Roll?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller

I try this :

```
 UIImagePickerController *videoPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
videoPicker.delegate = self;
videoPicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
videoPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
videoPicker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString*)kUTTypeMovie, (NSString*)kUTTypeAVIMovie, (NSString*)kUTTypeVideo, (NSString*)kUTTypeMPEG4];
videoPicker.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh;
[self presentViewController:videoPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

but it only show videos from photos part not all video in camera roll.
I want to pick all video from Camera roll.
Please help me by giving some clue or code.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://github.com/questbeat/QBImagePicker Might be help you

Comment: Set mediaTypes like `videoPicker.mediaTypes =[UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];` and try to execute your code.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is a compilation and cleanup of the answer above plus a few more details.

(0) Ensure you have these two includes.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h> // needed for video types
```

(1) Add two delegates to your .h file: UINavigationControllerDelegate and UIImagePickerControllerDelegate. For us, it looked like this:

```
@interface ATHViewController () <UITabBarDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
```

(2) Present the user with choice of videos from their library. Add this code to your .m file somewhere.

```
    // Present videos from which to choose
    UIImagePickerController *videoPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    videoPicker.delegate = self; // ensure you set the delegate so when a video is chosen the right method can be called

    videoPicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    // This code ensures only videos are shown to the end user
    videoPicker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString*)kUTTypeMovie, (NSString*)kUTTypeAVIMovie, (NSString*)kUTTypeVideo, (NSString*)kUTTypeMPEG4];

    videoPicker.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh;
    [self presentViewController:videoPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

(3) Handle the responses from the picker. Add this code to your delegate class.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    // This is the NSURL of the video object
    NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];

    NSLog(@"VideoURL = %@", videoURL);
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

(4) Handle when the user cancels choosing anything.

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Please use the following code to select video from iOS gallery

```
UIImagePickerController *videoPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
videoPicker.delegate = self;
videoPicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
videoPicker.mediaTypes =[UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];‌​
videoPicker.mediaTypes = @[(NSString*)kUTTypeMovie, (NSString*)kUTTypeAVIMovie, (NSString*)kUTTypeVideo, (NSString*)kUTTypeMPEG4];
videoPicker.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh;
[self presentViewController:videoPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Please have a look at this link [Select video from gallery](http://beageek.biz/saveload-imagevideos-camera-roll-xcode-ios/)

Comment: #import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>  to get rid of the error "undeclared identifier type kuTTypeAVIMovie" from this code

Comment: Aren't you overwriting values to videoPicker.mediatypes here? (Your first value is getting ignored.) You can delete your first definition of videoPicker.mediaTypes and this code still appears to be working.