# Flutter image_picker choose video

Tags: flutter

I am successfully using the Flutter Plugin Image_picker to choose images so that I can use them for upload, display, etc...  I wondered if anyone had any guidance on how to modify this plugin to also see videos and allow them to be chosen and use for upload, etc...

Looking for iOS and Android modifications if anyone has guidance on how to proceed or example code. I have made some progress but still need to get the camera to save video and be able to present.  I will post the code changes so far.  I have it selecting a video, but it will not present back to the app.

```
// Copyright 2017 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

@import UIKit;
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>

#import "ImagePickerPlugin.h"

@interface ImagePickerPlugin ()<UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
@end

static const int SOURCE_ASK_USER = 0;
static const int SOURCE_CAMERA = 1;
static const int SOURCE_GALLERY = 2;

@implementation ImagePickerPlugin {
  FlutterResult _result;
  NSDictionary *_arguments;
  UIImagePickerController *_imagePickerController;
  UIViewController *_viewController;
}

+ (void)registerWithRegistrar:(NSObject<FlutterPluginRegistrar> *)registrar {
  FlutterMethodChannel *channel =
      [FlutterMethodChannel methodChannelWithName:@"image_picker"
                                  binaryMessenger:[registrar messenger]];
  UIViewController *viewController =
      [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController;
  ImagePickerPlugin *instance = [[ImagePickerPlugin alloc] initWithViewController:viewController];
  [registrar addMethodCallDelegate:instance channel:channel];
}

- (instancetype)initWithViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    _viewController = viewController;
    _imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
  }
  return self;
}

- (void)handleMethodCall:(FlutterMethodCall *)call result:(FlutterResult)result {
  if (_result) {
    _result([FlutterError errorWithCode:@"multiple_request"
                                message:@"Cancelled by a second request"
                                details:nil]);
    _result = nil;
  }

  if ([@"pickImage" isEqualToString:call.method]) {
    _imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    _imagePickerController.delegate = self;

    _result = result;
    _arguments = call.arguments;

    int imageSource = [[_arguments objectForKey:@"source"] intValue];

    switch (imageSource) {
      case SOURCE_ASK_USER:
        [self showImageSourceSelector];
        break;
      case SOURCE_CAMERA:
        [self showCamera];
        break;
      case SOURCE_GALLERY:
        [self showPhotoLibrary];
        break;
      default:
        result([FlutterError errorWithCode:@"invalid_source"
                                   message:@"Invalid image source."
                                   details:nil]);
        break;
    }
  } else {
    result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented);
  }
}

- (void)showImageSourceSelector {
  UIAlertControllerStyle style = UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad
                                     ? UIAlertControllerStyleAlert
                                     : UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet;

  UIAlertController *alert =
      [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:nil preferredStyle:style];
  UIAlertAction *camera = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Take Photo"
                                                   style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                 handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                                                   [self showCamera];
                                                 }];
  UIAlertAction *library = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Choose Photo"
                                                    style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                  handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                                                    [self showPhotoLibrary];
                                                  }];


  UIAlertAction *cancel =
      [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:nil];
  [alert addAction:camera];
  [alert addAction:library];
  [alert addAction:cancel];
  [_viewController presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)showCamera {
  // Camera is not available on simulators
  if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
    _imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerCameraCaptureModeVideo;
    [_viewController presentViewController:_imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
  } else {
    [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                message:@"Camera not available."
                               delegate:nil
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                      otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
  }
}

- (void)showPhotoLibrary {
  // No need to check if SourceType is available. It always is.
  //_imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    _imagePickerController.mediaTypes =[UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:_imagePickerController.sourceType];
  [_viewController presentViewController:_imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
    didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)info {
  [_imagePickerController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
  UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
  NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
  if (image == nil) {
    image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
  } else {
      image = [self normalizedImage:image];
  }
  if (videoURL == nil) {

  } else {
      //image = videoURL;
  }


  NSNumber *maxWidth = [_arguments objectForKey:@"maxWidth"];
  NSNumber *maxHeight = [_arguments objectForKey:@"maxHeight"];

  if (maxWidth != (id)[NSNull null] || maxHeight != (id)[NSNull null]) {
    image = [self scaledImage:image maxWidth:maxWidth maxHeight:maxHeight];
  }

  NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
  NSString *tmpDirectory = NSTemporaryDirectory();
  NSString *guid = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] globallyUniqueString];
  // TODO(jackson): Using the cache directory might be better than temporary
  // directory.
  NSString *tmpFile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image_picker_%@.jpg", guid];
  NSString *tmpPath = [tmpDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:tmpFile];
  if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:tmpPath contents:data attributes:nil]) {
    _result(tmpPath);
  } else {
    _result([FlutterError errorWithCode:@"create_error"
                                message:@"Temporary file could not be created"
                                details:nil]);
  }
  _result = nil;
  _arguments = nil;
}

// The way we save images to the tmp dir currently throws away all EXIF data
// (including the orientation of the image). That means, pics taken in portrait
// will not be orientated correctly as is. To avoid that, we rotate the actual
// image data.
// TODO(goderbauer): investigate how to preserve EXIF data.
- (UIImage *)normalizedImage:(UIImage *)image {
  if (image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) return image;

  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, NO, image.scale);
  [image drawInRect:(CGRect){0, 0, image.size}];
  UIImage *normalizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
  return normalizedImage;
}


- (UIImage *)scaledImage:(UIImage *)image
                maxWidth:(NSNumber *)maxWidth
               maxHeight:(NSNumber *)maxHeight {
  double originalWidth = image.size.width;
  double originalHeight = image.size.height;

  bool hasMaxWidth = maxWidth != (id)[NSNull null];
  bool hasMaxHeight = maxHeight != (id)[NSNull null];

  double width = hasMaxWidth ? MIN([maxWidth doubleValue], originalWidth) : originalWidth;
  double height = hasMaxHeight ? MIN([maxHeight doubleValue], originalHeight) : originalHeight;

  bool shouldDownscaleWidth = hasMaxWidth && [maxWidth doubleValue] < originalWidth;
  bool shouldDownscaleHeight = hasMaxHeight && [maxHeight doubleValue] < originalHeight;
  bool shouldDownscale = shouldDownscaleWidth || shouldDownscaleHeight;

  if (shouldDownscale) {
    double downscaledWidth = (height / originalHeight) * originalWidth;
    double downscaledHeight = (width / originalWidth) * originalHeight;

    if (width < height) {
      if (!hasMaxWidth) {
        width = downscaledWidth;
      } else {
        height = downscaledHeight;
      }
    } else if (height < width) {
      if (!hasMaxHeight) {
        height = downscaledHeight;
      } else {
        width = downscaledWidth;
      }
    } else {
      if (originalWidth < originalHeight) {
        width = downscaledWidth;
      } else if (originalHeight < originalWidth) {
        height = downscaledHeight;
      }
    }
  }

  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(width, height), NO, 1.0);
  [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)];

  UIImage *scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

  return scaledImage;
}

@end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is the IOS code that I have completed, I am still working on the Android if anyone wants to assist, I will post where I am at so far.  This code replaces what is in the .m file of the IOS folder, no other changes are needed for this to work to pick and capture video along with images.  You must figure out how to display the selected video/image in your app, but that's however you want to handle it.  Again let me know if you want to assist with finishing he Android side.

```
@import UIKit;
#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>

#import "MediaPickerPlugin.h"

@interface MediaPickerPlugin ()<UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate>
@end

static const int SOURCE_ASK_USER = 0;
//static const int SOURCE_CAMERA = 0;
//static const int SOURCE_GALLERY = 0;

@implementation MediaPickerPlugin {
    FlutterResult _result;
    NSDictionary *_arguments;
    UIImagePickerController *_imagePickerController;
    UIViewController *_viewController;
}

+ (void)registerWithRegistrar:(NSObject<FlutterPluginRegistrar> *)registrar {
    FlutterMethodChannel *channel =
    [FlutterMethodChannel methodChannelWithName:@"media_picker"
                                binaryMessenger:[registrar messenger]];
    UIViewController *viewController =
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController;
    MediaPickerPlugin *instance =
        [[MediaPickerPlugin alloc] initWithViewController:viewController];
    [registrar addMethodCallDelegate:instance channel:channel];
}

- (instancetype)initWithViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
      _viewController = viewController;
      _imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)handleMethodCall:(FlutterMethodCall *)call result:(FlutterResult)result {
  if (_result) {
    _result([FlutterError errorWithCode:@"multiple_request"
                                message:@"Cancelled by a second request"
                                details:nil]);
    _result = nil;
      _arguments = nil;
}

if ([@"pickImage" isEqualToString:call.method]) {
  _imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
  _imagePickerController.delegate = self;

  _result = result;
  _arguments = call.arguments;

  int imageSource = [[_arguments objectForKey:@"source"] intValue];

    switch (imageSource) {
        case SOURCE_ASK_USER:
            [self showImageSourceSelector];
            break;
        default:
            result([FlutterError errorWithCode:@"invalid_source"
                                       message:@"Invalid image source."
                                       details:nil]);
            break;
        }
    } else {
      result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented);
    }
}

- (void)showImageSourceSelector {
    UIAlertControllerStyle style = UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad
                                        ? UIAlertControllerStyleAlert
                                        : UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet;

    UIAlertController *alert =
        [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:nil preferredStyle:style];
    UIAlertAction *camera = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Camera"
                                                     style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                   handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                                                       [self showCamera];
                                                   }];
    UIAlertAction *library = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Gallery"
                                                      style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                    handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {
                                                        [self showPhotoLibrary];
                                                    }];
    UIAlertAction *cancel =
    [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:nil];
    [alert addAction:camera];
    [alert addAction:library];
    [alert addAction:cancel];
    [_viewController presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)showCamera {
    // Camera is not available on simulators
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
        _imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        _imagePickerController.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"public.movie", @"public.image", nil];
        _imagePickerController.delegate = self;
        _imagePickerController.restoresFocusAfterTransition = false;
        _imagePickerController.allowsEditing = NO;
        _imagePickerController.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeLow;
        _imagePickerController.videoMaximumDuration = 30.0f; // 30 seconds
        [_viewController presentViewController:_imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
    } else {
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                    message:@"Camera not available."
                                   delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    }
}

- (void)showPhotoLibrary {
// No need to check if SourceType is available. It always is.
_imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    _imagePickerController.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"public.movie", @"public.image", nil];
//_imagePickerController.mediaTypes =[UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:_imagePickerController.sourceType];
[_viewController presentViewController:_imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
      didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *, id> *)info {
  [_imagePickerController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
  NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
  if ([mediaType isEqualToString:@"public.movie"]) {
    NSURL *videoURL = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    NSString *videoString = [videoURL absoluteString];
    NSLog(@"Video File:%@", videoString);
    _result(videoString);
  } else {
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    if (image == nil) {
      image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    }
    image = [self normalizedImage:image];

    NSNumber *maxWidth = [_arguments objectForKey:@"maxWidth"];
    NSNumber *maxHeight = [_arguments objectForKey:@"maxHeight"];

    if (maxWidth != (id)[NSNull null] || maxHeight != (id)[NSNull null]) {
      image = [self scaledImage:image maxWidth:maxWidth maxHeight:maxHeight];
    }

    NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0);
    NSString *tmpDirectory = NSTemporaryDirectory();
    NSString *guid = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] globallyUniqueString];
    // TODO(jackson): Using the cache directory might be better than temporary
    // directory.
    NSString *tmpFile = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image_picker_%@.jpg", guid];
    NSString *tmpPath = [tmpDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:tmpFile];
    NSLog(@"Image File:%@", tmpPath);
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:tmpPath contents:data attributes:nil]) {
        _result(tmpPath);
    } else {
        _result([FlutterError errorWithCode:@"create_error"
                                    message:@"Temporary file could not be created"
                                    details:nil]);
    }
      _result = nil;
      _arguments = nil;
  }
  _result = nil;
  _arguments = nil;
}

// The way we save images to the tmp dir currently throws away all EXIF data
    // (including the orientation of the image). That means, pics taken in portrait
    // will not be orientated correctly as is. To avoid that, we rotate the actual
    // image data.
// TODO(goderbauer): investigate how to preserve EXIF data.
- (UIImage *)normalizedImage:(UIImage *)image {
    if (image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) return image;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, NO, image.scale);
    [image drawInRect:(CGRect){0, 0, image.size}];
    UIImage *normalizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return normalizedImage;
}
//- (NSString *)normalVideo:(NSURL *)videoURL {
  //    NSString *normalVideo = UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL;
  //    return normalVideo;
//}

- (UIImage *)scaledImage:(UIImage *)image
    maxWidth:(NSNumber *)maxWidth
    maxHeight:(NSNumber *)maxHeight {
    double originalWidth = image.size.width;
    double originalHeight = image.size.height;

    bool hasMaxWidth = maxWidth != (id)[NSNull null];
    bool hasMaxHeight = maxHeight != (id)[NSNull null];

    double width = hasMaxWidth ? MIN([maxWidth doubleValue], originalWidth) : originalWidth;
    double height = hasMaxHeight ? MIN([maxHeight doubleValue], originalHeight) : originalHeight;

    bool shouldDownscaleWidth = hasMaxWidth && [maxWidth doubleValue] < originalWidth;
    bool shouldDownscaleHeight = hasMaxHeight && [maxHeight doubleValue] < originalHeight;
    bool shouldDownscale = shouldDownscaleWidth || shouldDownscaleHeight;

    if (shouldDownscale) {
          double downscaledWidth = (height / originalHeight) * originalWidth;
          double downscaledHeight = (width / originalWidth) * originalHeight;

          if (width < height) {
            if (!hasMaxWidth) {
              width = downscaledWidth;
            } else {
              height = downscaledHeight;
            }
          } else if (height < width) {
            if (!hasMaxHeight) {
              height = downscaledHeight;
            } else {
              width = downscaledWidth;
            }
          } else {
            if (originalWidth < originalHeight) {
              width = downscaledWidth;
            } else if (originalHeight < originalWidth) {
              height = downscaledHeight;
            }
          }
    }

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(width, height), NO, 1.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height)];

    UIImage *scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return scaledImage;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably add another method `pickVideo` to [`image_picker.dart`](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/image_picker/lib/image_picker.dart), and then add the corresponding Android and iOS implementations of that in [`imagePickerPlugin.m`](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/image_picker/ios/Classes/ImagePickerPlugin.m) and [`ImagePickerPlugin.java`](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/blob/master/packages/image_picker/android/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/imagepicker/ImagePickerPlugin.java).

Inside the latter two, I would use the iOS and Android APIs for videos, e.g. something like this on iOS:
[Objective c - ios : How to pick video from Camera Roll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30882321/objective-c-ios-how-to-pick-video-from-camera-roll)

Comment: Any code examples or have you done it before for this plugin?

Comment: Anyone have a code example, I have tried to see how the code would fit in the current plugin but not as well versed in Objective c right now.  I see how it could work, but not how to modify the current code to make the changes.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have it selecting video, but can not figure out how to get it to present back to the plugin, it crashes or hangs when I choose it, any thoughts or has anyone done it yet, need to capture video on camera too.

Comment: I have added some code I have been working on, but still looking for some assistance.

Comment: @Slabo I just posted my finished ios code, android is almost done, I will probably do a PR when I am complete or make a new one called media_picker and post as a package.

Comment: look at last comment here >> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48718551/capture-video-with-flutter seems solved.

Answer (score 0):

as of version 0.4.2, the plugin allows video to be selected

> Added support for picking videos. Updated example app to show video
>   preview.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that now using pickVideo available in image_picker

```
final _picker = ImagePicker();
PickedFile video = await _picker.getVideo(...)
...
```

Ref - https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker

Comment: but in your example code it says getVideo not pickVideo )

Answer (score -1):

you can use the image picker for recording video, and chewie library to show a video via video controller.
for more reference use this video link -
https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=17&v=XSn5EwWBG-4&feature=emb_logo