# Capture video with flutter

Tags: video, plugins, camera, flutter, video-recording

Hi I am in the process of developing an app with flutter with video recording functionality. I have come across 2 plugins with ability to capture/save an image as a file with flutter:

[Camera v0.0.2](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/camera) and [Image_picker v0.2.1](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image_picker) , they work well and are official flutter plugins.

In essence I would like to build a mini camera plugin with video recording capabilities with flutter, which would work with iOS and Android seamlessly.

Any suggestions, direction, methods to upgrade these plugins are welcome.

Comment: I'm trying to build out this feature with some help, wish me luck!

Comment: I was trying same, to record video in flutter dart.
cameras = await availableCameras(); is not returning any results.

Did you succeed in this?

Comment: We actually did, we sent a pull request, fingers crossed

Comment: Hi Nissim, any chances that I can get a early preview.
sachinpatel248@gmail.com

Comment: I shall let you know as soon as we hear back from Google.

Comment: You can preview the plugin by adding this to your yaml: camera git with      url: https://github.com/Tengio/plugins.git, path: packages/camera and ref: dd75acce3d2166b6a18fbd9641270a398b86cf51

Comment: Hello, hello.. Any updates? Any progress? I can't find any examples on this.

Comment: We are working on the plugin and close to completion, you can have a preview here of the plugin: https://github.com/Tengio/plugins/tree/master/packages/camera
with an example app.
You can keep up-to-date with the pull request with the main flutter repo is here:
https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/458

Once the pull is final I shall post an answer to this question.

Comment: @Nissim seems all checks accepted. Thanks.

Comment: Now that your changes have passed all checks, when do they merge the changes? newb question, dunno how google does this.

Comment: In all honesty neither do we, but if you do want to use the plugin, you can with the latest commit to the forked repo: github.com/Tengio/plugins.git

All check with respect to the green ticks at the bottom of the PR is an indication that all automated checks are in place.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Video recording is now enabled by our team on the official **[camera plugin](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/camera) v0.2.0**

by submitting a [pull request](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/458) to the repository.

The example app for this plugin uses additional plugins [path_provider](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/path_provider)
 and [video_player](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/video_player) to display a sample of the video recorded.

Hope this helps other flutter developers cheers!

Comment: I can't get the example code to work. I'm getting this runtime error >> compiler message: file:///Users/doudou/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/camera-0.2.0/lib/camera.dart:188:21: Error: Method not found: 'CameraValue.uninitialized'.
compiler message:       : super(const CameraValue.uninitialized());

Comment: Did you run `flutter upgrade` and `flutter doctor` ? I just did a clean  re-install of the flutter plugins and it worked after upgrading to the latest versions recommended by flutter doctor.

Comment: yes. Works just fine. I switched to beta channel and upgraded to Flutter 0.5.1. works just fine. all examples work just fine. Now integrating into my project. Thanks a bunch

Comment: how can we display video using thumbnail ? if i pick multiple video need to display it as grid with a preview button.

Comment: If you check the example app on the camera plugin, you will see a thumbnail of the recently captured video. Currently we do not have a preview screen on the example app, this flutter link https://flutter.io/tutorials/layout/#common-layout-widgets  can help you build it.

Comment: If I have the IP Webcam running on another device, could this record from it?

Comment: Well this is a on device camera app, so no it would not work. For an IP camera you might need to connect via a websocket. you can find more here: https://flutter.io/cookbook/networking/web-sockets/

Comment: I keep getting ```FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/8404343A-8459-4EBF-911D-181C65DA516F/Documents/Videos/1581396279484.mp4' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)``` no matter. Pictures work fine.

Answer (score 4):

Flutter provides a packages "camera" and "video_player". Camera is used for accessing the camera of the phone and video_plater is used for video recording. You can use the camera package and record the video. You can find the code below:

> First you have to update the pubspec file like:

```
dependencies:
   camera: ^0.2.9+1
   fluttertoast: 
   path_provider:
   video_player:
```

> fluttertoast is the toast for your camera and path_provider provides that path where your video will be saved. Then you have to import those packages into your dart file and write your own implementation. you can find the sample code below. It opens the available list of cameras in your phone including the external cameras so that you can choose any one of them to record your video.

```
import 'dart:async';
  import 'dart:io';

  import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
  import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';
  import 'package:fluttertoast/fluttertoast.dart';

  class VideoRecorderExample extends StatefulWidget {
    @override
    _VideoRecorderExampleState createState() {
      return _VideoRecorderExampleState();
    }
  }

  class _VideoRecorderExampleState extends State<VideoRecorderExample> {
    CameraController controller;
    String videoPath;

    List<CameraDescription> cameras;
    int selectedCameraIdx;

    final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

    @override
    void initState() {
      super.initState();

      // Get the listonNewCameraSelected of available cameras.
      // Then set the first camera as selected.
      availableCameras()
          .then((availableCameras) {
        cameras = availableCameras;

        if (cameras.length > 0) {
          setState(() {
            selectedCameraIdx = 0;
          });

          _onCameraSwitched(cameras[selectedCameraIdx]).then((void v) {});
        }
      })
          .catchError((err) {
        print('Error: $err.code\nError Message: $err.message');
      });
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Camera example'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1.0),
                  child: Center(
                    child: _cameraPreviewWidget(),
                  ),
                ),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  border: Border.all(
                    color: controller != null && controller.value.isRecordingVideo
                        ? Colors.redAccent
                        : Colors.grey,
                    width: 3.0,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  _cameraTogglesRowWidget(),
                  _captureControlRowWidget(),
                  Expanded(
                    child: SizedBox(),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }

    IconData _getCameraLensIcon(CameraLensDirection direction) {
      switch (direction) {
        case CameraLensDirection.back:
          return Icons.camera_rear;
        case CameraLensDirection.front:
          return Icons.camera_front;
        case CameraLensDirection.external:
          return Icons.camera;
        default:
          return Icons.device_unknown;
      }
    }

    // Display 'Loading' text when the camera is still loading.
    Widget _cameraPreviewWidget() {
      if (controller == null || !controller.value.isInitialized) {
        return const Text(
          'Loading',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white,
            fontSize: 20.0,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
          ),
        );
      }

      return AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,
        child: CameraPreview(controller),
      );
    }

    /// Display a row of toggle to select the camera (or a message if no camera is available).
    Widget _cameraTogglesRowWidget() {
      if (cameras == null) {
        return Row();
      }

      CameraDescription selectedCamera = cameras[selectedCameraIdx];
      CameraLensDirection lensDirection = selectedCamera.lensDirection;

      return Expanded(
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: FlatButton.icon(
              onPressed: _onSwitchCamera,
              icon: Icon(
                  _getCameraLensIcon(lensDirection)
              ),
              label: Text("${lensDirection.toString()
                  .substring(lensDirection.toString().indexOf('.')+1)}")
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    /// Display the control bar with buttons to record videos.
    Widget _captureControlRowWidget() {
      return Expanded(
        child: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.videocam),
                color: Colors.blue,
                onPressed: controller != null &&
                    controller.value.isInitialized &&
                    !controller.value.isRecordingVideo
                    ? _onRecordButtonPressed
                    : null,
              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.stop),
                color: Colors.red,
                onPressed: controller != null &&
                    controller.value.isInitialized &&
                    controller.value.isRecordingVideo
                    ? _onStopButtonPressed
                    : null,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    String timestamp() => DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();

    Future<void> _onCameraSwitched(CameraDescription cameraDescription) async {
      if (controller != null) {
        await controller.dispose();
      }

      controller = CameraController(cameraDescription, ResolutionPreset.high);

      // If the controller is updated then update the UI.
      controller.addListener(() {
        if (mounted) {
          setState(() {});
        }

        if (controller.value.hasError) {
          Fluttertoast.showToast(
              msg: 'Camera error ${controller.value.errorDescription}',
              toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
              gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
              timeInSecForIos: 1,
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
              textColor: Colors.white
          );
        }
      });

      try {
        await controller.initialize();
      } on CameraException catch (e) {
        _showCameraException(e);
      }

      if (mounted) {
        setState(() {});
      }
    }

    void _onSwitchCamera() {
      selectedCameraIdx = selectedCameraIdx < cameras.length - 1
          ? selectedCameraIdx + 1
          : 0;
      CameraDescription selectedCamera = cameras[selectedCameraIdx];

      _onCameraSwitched(selectedCamera);

      setState(() {
        selectedCameraIdx = selectedCameraIdx;
      });
    }

    void _onRecordButtonPressed() {
      _startVideoRecording().then((String filePath) {
        if (filePath != null) {
          Fluttertoast.showToast(
              msg: 'Recording video started',
              toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
              gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
              timeInSecForIos: 1,
              backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
              textColor: Colors.white
          );
        }
      });
    }

    void _onStopButtonPressed() {
      _stopVideoRecording().then((_) {
        if (mounted) setState(() {});
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
            msg: 'Video recorded to $videoPath',
            toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
            gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
            timeInSecForIos: 1,
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
            textColor: Colors.white
        );
      });
    }

    Future<String> _startVideoRecording() async {
      if (!controller.value.isInitialized) {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
            msg: 'Please wait',
            toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
            gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
            timeInSecForIos: 1,
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
            textColor: Colors.white
        );

        return null;
      }

      // Do nothing if a recording is on progress
      if (controller.value.isRecordingVideo) {
        return null;
      }

      final Directory appDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
      final String videoDirectory = '${appDirectory.path}/Videos';
      await Directory(videoDirectory).create(recursive: true);
      final String currentTime = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();
      final String filePath = '$videoDirectory/${currentTime}.mp4';

      try {
        await controller.startVideoRecording(filePath);
        videoPath = filePath;
      } on CameraException catch (e) {
        _showCameraException(e);
        return null;
      }

      return filePath;
    }

    Future<void> _stopVideoRecording() async {
      if (!controller.value.isRecordingVideo) {
        return null;
      }

      try {
        await controller.stopVideoRecording();
      } on CameraException catch (e) {
        _showCameraException(e);
        return null;
      }
    }

    void _showCameraException(CameraException e) {
      String errorText = 'Error: ${e.code}\nError Message: ${e.description}';
      print(errorText);

      Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: 'Error: ${e.code}\n${e.description}',
          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
          gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
          timeInSecForIos: 1,
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          textColor: Colors.white
      );
    }
  }

  class VideoRecorderApp extends StatelessWidget {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return MaterialApp(
        home: VideoRecorderExample(),
      );
    }
  }

  Future<void> main() async {
    runApp(VideoRecorderApp());
  }
```

Comment: ```FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = '/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/8404343A-8459-4EBF-911D-181C65DA516F/Documents/Videos/1581396279484.mp4' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)```