# How to access camera frames in flutter quickly

Tags: camera, flutter, flutter-plugin

I would like to implement near real-time OCR on the camera feed of my flutter app. To do this I would like to access the camera data in a speedy manner.
As far as I can tell I have two options, and have hit roadblocks with both:

1. Take a screenshot of the `CameraPreview` by putting a `RepaintBoundary` around it and creating a `RenderRepaintBoundary`, and calling `boundary.toImage()`. The problem with this method is that the .toImage method only seems to capture the painted widgets in the boundary and not the data from the camera preview. Simmilar to the issue described here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/17687
2. Capture an image with `controller.takePicture(filePath)` from Camera 0.2.1, similar to the example docs. The problem here is that it takes super long before the image becomes available (2-3 seconds). I guess that this is because the file is saved to the disc on capture and then needs to be read from the file again.

Is there any way that one can directly access the picture information after capture, to do things like pre-process and OCR?

Comment: This is a long shot, but can you grab frames from a video? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48718551/capture-video-with-flutter

Comment: Would you be doing the OCR in OpenCV?

Comment: My plan was to crop the frames and use the ml-kit to access the text-recogniser, using the mk-kit plugin: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/mlkit

Comment: @dazza5000 I think the video recording also has to first save the file to the disk before it can be accessed, which means that I would sit with the same problem..

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope not yet. Holding my breath for news from the devs re: update to the Camera package.

Comment: I'm trying to find a solution to this problem as well. I'm thinking with access to the camera's stream you could pipe that buffer into 'ml_vision' then use FirebaseVisionDetectors and CustomPainters to paint. There's two problems: 1 ) No access to the Camera stream (output) 2 ) 'FirebaseVisionDetector' lacks the capability to detect from a stream.

Comment: So it seems the flutter team has come through, camera 0.2.8 brings with it access to the image stream from Dart using cameraController.startImageStream(listener) to process the images. Unfortunately I cannot yet find any documentation or examples of how to use this, but I'm sure it will follow soon.

Comment: this post might helpful for you.. https://blog.usejournal.com/real-time-object-detection-in-flutter-b31c7ff9ef96

Comment: I posted my answer, I hope you find it useful

Answer (score 25):

For "near real-time OCR", you need `CameraController#startImageStream`

example code

```
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: _MyHomePage()));

class _MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<_MyHomePage> {
  dynamic _scanResults;
  CameraController _camera;

  bool _isDetecting = false;
  CameraLensDirection _direction = CameraLensDirection.back;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initializeCamera();
  }

  Future<CameraDescription> _getCamera(CameraLensDirection dir) async {
    return await availableCameras().then(
      (List<CameraDescription> cameras) => cameras.firstWhere(
            (CameraDescription camera) => camera.lensDirection == dir,
          ),
    );
  }

  void _initializeCamera() async {
    _camera = CameraController(
      await _getCamera(_direction),
      defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS
          ? ResolutionPreset.low
          : ResolutionPreset.medium,
    );
    await _camera.initialize();
    _camera.startImageStream((CameraImage image) {
      if (_isDetecting) return;
      _isDetecting = true;
      try {
        // await doSomethingWith(image)
      } catch (e) {
        // await handleExepction(e)
      } finally {
        _isDetecting = false;
      }
    });
  }
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return null;
  }
}
```

This functionality was merged to https://github.com/flutter/plugins but it was not well documented.

Ref:

- https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26348
- https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/965
- https://github.com/bparrishMines/mlkit_demo/blob/master/lib/main.dart#L43
- https://youtu.be/OAEWySye0BQ?t=1460

Comment: Are you able to draw on the image in real time as well and thus manipulate the camera's recording?

Comment: ''Future<CameraDescription> _getCamera(CameraLensDirection dir) async {
    return await availableCameras().then(
      (List<CameraDescription> cameras) => cameras.firstWhere(
            (CameraDescription camera) => camera.lensDirection == dir,
          ),
    );
  }'Unhandled Exception: Bad state: No element  ListMixin.firstWhere

Comment: how to create a video out of these images ?

Answer (score 0):

A better solution today (2022) for real-time OCR is to use the camera in a loop with a frequency of 500ms and process the image using google ML Kit's Text recognition.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more on the "use the camera in a loop"? Do you mean to take static photos, instead of a video? Would the user simply see 2 fps for the camera feed tho?

Comment: @WSBT - Yes for photos and no, it doesn't affect what the user sees on the camera preview screen, as far as I have tested it.

Comment: By "take a photo" do you mean to take a photo (save it to disk as a file), then read the file again? Or do you mean somehow grab a snapshot using the stream api and cancel the stream after getting one snapshot?